# Unusual disabling behavior with Command buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

*I'm sorry for this being so wordy, but I want to make the situation perfectly clear. Please, if you are a WPF pro, take a look.*

There are two `CollectionViewSource` bound to `ItemsControls` that use `UserControl` Views to display either `StackPanels` or custom `Buttons`. There is one for each side shown in the screenshot below. The problem I'm encountering is that when the parent collection property is set, all of the buttons in the `DataTemplate` view are disabled. Even the 2 buttons higher up are having the same problem even though they worked before my recent edits.

If I click on the form, or press any key, the buttons enable. As soon as the property is reset to a newly edited and sorted collection, they disable again. Rinse and repeat. This is what it looks like. The first frame is how it starts (gray using `StackPanel`), the 2nd is what it looks like when the RFS button is clicked, and the 3rd frame is what happens when I click anywhere or press a key.

[image: Disable-Enable behavior]

I've been going in circles trying out things. The only thing that seems to work is a code-behind workaround that sets focus to one thing and then back. However, that would not be good for the user if they are trying to use one of the other dashboard items.

Since the WPF for all of this is very massive, I'll try to include just the relevant parts. These are the `ItemsControls` on the TabItemControl (`UserControl`).

```
        <!-- BID (SELL) DEPTH -->
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="bidDepthList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BidDepthCollection}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMultilegEnabled, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedConverter}}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DepthLevelViewModel}">
                 <v:DepthLevelRowView x:Name="BidDepthLevelRowViewControl" DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,0,1,3" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <!-- ASK (BUY) DEPTH -->
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="askDepthList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AskDepthCollection}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMultilegEnabled, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedConverter}}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DepthLevelViewModel}">
                 <v:DepthLevelRowView x:Name="AskDepthLevelRowViewControl" DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,0,1,3" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The view being used has 4 "controls" inside of a grid. Only one of them is displayed at a time depending on the state (RFS OFF/RFS ON) and which side they are on (Sell/Buy). The others are collapsed. As you can see, this is fine.

The only common factor between them is that they have their `Command` set, as do most of the controls at the top that are disabling/enabling correctly. The fact that the buttons enable correctly if any mouse or keyboard action is taken tells me that the `CanExecute` handler is working, just not immediately. The other controls started working after I made **[these changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144448/6131481)**, but then the big buttons started misbehaving like the depth buttons have been doing.

I've tried using `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` after altering the collections, but that didn't help.

**NOTE:** This is also happening even for something as simple as this:

```
<Button x:Name="TestBuyButton" Command="{x:Static ptcommands:OrderCommands.Buy}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Content="Test Buy" />
```

I know the booleans are set correctly because I added test CheckBoxes to display the current value with IsChecked. And, they all enable, including the extremely basic Button, as soon as any input action is taken.

**Is there something else I'm missing or a different approach I can take?**

---

**EDIT:** I ended up using the `Dispatcher` to invoke my display update routine from the event thread over to the UI thread. The boolean values get set, but WPF still didn't requery the `Command`. BUT.. the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` call then worked! The only thing I don't like about that is it sounds like a broadcast invalidation. I don't want all commands to be requeried. I just want the Buy and Sell commands to requery. I've tried all sorts of weirdness trying to get just those to work, but nothing has worked so far other than the global.

**EDIT 2:** It appears as though the `InvalidateRequerySuggested` is the way to go.

From MSDN **[`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

> The CommandManager only pays attention to certain conditions in determining when the command target has changed, such as change in keyboard focus. In situations where the CommandManager does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, InvalidateRequerySuggested can be called to force the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event.

This would explain why the focus changes and keypresses would cause the buttons to enable. The page also shows putting the call in a timer. Because of this, I assume it is not as resource intensive as I thought. So, I guess it's my permanent solution.

Comment: I made [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342247/accessing-the-first-item-in-a-collectionviewsource-containing-multithreaded-obse) regarding some changes I made as part of trying to fix this. Since it now only populates once and just updates what it has, it's only disabled once. I can click on the form and it doesn't disable again. I don't know if it will when I add/remove again as the current process just populates really fast and then alters existing items. So, technically, the disabling problem still exists.

Comment: I just made a large edit to this post to reflect the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to get the buttons to enable without focus changes.

The boolean values were being set within a method called from an event thread. I had tried calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` along with it, but nothing happened. Eventually I thought it might have something to do with the thread. This is what ended up resolving it.

In the parent form that the tab manager class (containing the event handlers and other logic) has access to, I added an invoke method:

```
  Public Sub InvokeOnUiThread(ByRef uiAction As Action, Optional ByRef doAsync As Boolean = False)

     Dim dispatchObject As Dispatcher = orderTicketView.Dispatcher

     If (dispatchObject Is Nothing OrElse dispatchObject.CheckAccess()) Then
        uiAction()
     Else
        If doAsync Then
           dispatchObject.BeginInvoke(uiAction, DispatcherPriority.Normal)
        Else
           dispatchObject.Invoke(uiAction, DispatcherPriority.Normal)
        End If
     End If

  End Sub
```

In the tab manager event handler, I changed it to call the update routine through the invoker:

```
formOrderTicketView.InvokeOnUiThread(New Action(AddressOf UpdateButtons))
```

At the bottom of the `UpdateButtons` method, I added a call to the `CommandManager` if a change has been made that would require a requery:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
```

I do not know what type of performance hit this would have, but apparently WPF executes it in its own way when focus changes and such. Calling it directly is the advised way to force it.

From MSDN **[`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

> The CommandManager only pays attention to certain conditions in determining when the command target has changed, such as change in keyboard focus. In situations where the CommandManager does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, InvalidateRequerySuggested can be called to force the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event.

Since it is working now, I am taking this as the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The command that's bound to the button...is there a CanExecute delegate with it? If so, you have to raise CanExecuteChanged when that delegate should be re-evaluated. Also, make sure the implementation of CanExecute isn't broken and incorrectly returning false;

Comment: I didn't add in more scenario notes because it would've been even more wordy, but... as part of my initial design tests before moving it to a view, I put the button directly in the DataTemplate. It did not get the disabled effect like it's doing now, and the command worked fine, but the background converter quit working. Now the converter works, and the alternate display works. It's just that bizarre disabling until click or keypress.

Comment: Additionally, the commands are all defined as GlobalRoutedUICommands, which itself is a class that inherits RoutedUICommand and implements INotifyPropertyChanged, in the OrderCommands class. The EventHandlers are defined in a 2nd level view model that all of the other view models inherit and allow other classes, such as the tab manager, to subscribe to.

I've looked around, and I don't see any CanExecute delegates. The big buttons above the lists are using the same command structure from the same OrderCommands class, too.

Comment: I also want to add that this is a trading platform that has threads firing all over the place at all times. Updates of all sorts are happening anywhere. Anything that would cause a performance issue needs to be avoided. All of the commands are executable at any time. The code-behind does the check when needed. So, if CanExecute always returning True would help, I can try to figure out where to put it. I didn't architect this thing.

Comment: I edited my initial post to include how the commands are declared. I've tried finding ways to use CanExecute, but everything I have found assumes that the commands are declared within the same form, and none of them are `RoutedUICommand`. I'm hoping that seeing the command declarations will help in some way.

Comment: I commented everything out of `CanExecuteCustomCommand` above and only had `e.CanExecute = true`, but no change. The buttons are still disabled until I click the form. My boss is getting mad. Ugh.

Comment: Sounds like the commands aren't initializing until the form has focus. It's been a while since I've worked on WPF or Forms.....but I believe there's a Focus() method you can call on the form when it loads to make sure it has focus

Comment: It definitely does seem like WPF isn't even querying the CanExecute of the nested buttons. The tab level ones are bound to the same set of RoutedUICommands, and they respond just fine. It's only the nested ones that refuse to enable. I tried to simply set Focus, but that only enabled the first button of each list. So, my ugly hack now sets focus to the list and back to the "RFS" button each time the collection count changes. Obviously this is a horrible solution that is way outside of MVVM and WPF convention, but it's the only thing that has worked so far.

Comment: If there's a way to trigger the CanExecute on the nested buttons when the command bindings are set, that might be a better solution. Manually setting focus is more of an "acts of desperation" fix.

Comment: I agree. In my internal Bugzilla comment, I called it "an ugly hack". I tried forcing the CanExecute on the DataContextChanged and in other places, but it just didn't do anything. Since this particular task has dragged on for over 3 weeks, I'm at the point of desperation.

Comment: !!!! That hack has gone back to not working. Only the first item in the list gets enabled. I'm about to lose my mind on this.

Comment: Maybe it's because there's no property changed notification from the command? That might explain why the buttons get disabled when the item changes. If the UI does it's bindings before the command is there, and the command property doesn't trigger a change notification, the button won't see it. That's happened to me before....but in a WP app with a much less complex UI and ViewModels

Comment: The thing that is really confusing me is that the big buttons directly on the tab container control are bound to Commands the same way, and they don't have the problem. It's like WPF just doesn't know what to do when they are ItemsControl -> DataTemplate -> View -> (Button). Considering all of them return True for CanExecute, there's no reason for them to disable that way. :-/

Comment: btw.. Those buttons also worked fine when I set them directly as the DataTemplate, but their BackgroundConverter didn't work. So, it's definitely something to do with the way the whole thing is being handled. Unfortunately, this monstrosity is not of my design, so I can't break it down into more manageable pieces.