# Why would multiple IsEnabled bindings fail to work?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The main ViewModel that is the DataContext for the tab content control contains A LOT of properties. The model itself implements an abstract class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. EVERY property set and get runs through the methods of the abstract class. So, they are all fully registered with notification, and most of them work fine.

I have a single boolean property bound to the `IsEnabled` property of many controls on the content control. This is because the user shouldn't change values while it is running server queries. The binding is exactly the same for all of the controls:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsIndicative}"
```

Almost every single control bound like that is a `RadComboBox` (Telerik). Only **1** is responding to the binding. In the screenshot, the "None" combobox is disabled, but all of the others aren't. They are the exact same type, and they are all using the same parent DataContext's property.

[image: Binding Failure]

I cannot determine why one of them is responding to the binding, but the others are ignoring it. It's also happening with the date dropdown you can see, but that's nested in a View, and I'll get to it later.

**I need help determining what is going on with the `IsEnabled` binding and why it is ignoring it.**

Additional Note: I had even added code-behind as a workaround in VS2012, but now even that appears to have quit working!

```
     StrategyTypeComboBox.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     QuantityNumericUpDown.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     datePicker.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     OptionsOrderTypeComboBox.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     ExpirationTypeComboBox.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     DeltaHedgeTypeComboBox.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     TopPriceTypeToggle.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
     PriceInTypeComboBox.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
```

**Example of the XAML**

All of the controls have this same exact setup. The only real difference is which `Grid.Row` they are in. Obviously the TextBlock and RadComboBox have some differences, but the layout and control orientation are exactly the same.

```xml
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,3,5,3">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- strategy_type label -->
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- dotted line -->
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TopLeftGridValues" /> <!-- StrategyTypeComboBox -->
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=MainLabelTextColor}" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,2,0"  Height="Auto">
              <TextBlock.Text>
                 <Binding Path="strategy_type" Source="{x:Static util:Strings.Instance}" />
              </TextBlock.Text>
           </TextBlock>
           <Line Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DottedLineStyle}" />
           <telerikInput:RadComboBox Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" MinWidth="60" Margin="3,0,3,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     x:Name="StrategyTypeComboBox"
                                     IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsIndicative}"
                                     Command="{x:Static ptcommands:OrderCommands.StrategyChanged}"
                                     CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StrategyTypesCollection}"
                                     DisplayMemberPath="display"
                                     SelectedValuePath="value"
                                     SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=StrategyTypeSelectedIndex}">
              <telerikInput:RadComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </telerikInput:RadComboBox.ItemsPanel>

           </telerikInput:RadComboBox>
        </Grid> <!-- Row 0: Strategy -->
```

Comment: maybe data context is wrong. so it cannot find the path correctly. show some code. a few samples

Comment: It's the same DataContext. All of the values in the Comboboxes come from collection properties, the converters for the button colors and various visibilities are coming from a boolean property, etc. It's hard to show examples due to the amount of work being done, and I'm only allowed to show the minimum. All of those controls are relatively at the same level (inside of a grid cell), and all are using `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsIndicative}"`

Comment: To clarify, the similar hierarchy between them all is 1 parent grid, then in each grid row is another grid with column 0 containing the label, column 1 containing a line (which is invisible due to black on black), and column 2 containing the RadComboBox. Repeat the grid row contents for each one.

Comment: The only similarity I can find is that it's always the `RadComboBox` that is acting up. In the row View (quantity, date, etc), everything disables except the comboboxes as well. I just think it's really odd that one of them is responding, but the others aren't. I'm not finding any special coding that would prevent the others from disabling.

Comment: I added the XAML for one of the Grid rows. All of them follow the same layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer someone else posted that pointed me in the right direction is gone. So, I'm creating this answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

The key issue is the `Command` property and its corresponding `CanExecute` functionality will override the `IsEnabled` property. In our case, the `CanExecute` method was always returning true, so the control would not disable. A centralized base view handles all of the command bindings, so it was not coded to check specifically for if a command really could be executed or not. There's also a central ViewModel that is bound to that view for use across the entire window.

To resolve this issue, I had to do the following:

- Create boolean properties on the ViewModel that could be set from the tab manager using the same values as the tab-specific values being bound.
- Add some `List<string>` fields to contain control names that should be affected by the various values. I will probably change this to examine the command itself (similar to how our `Executed` handler does it), but this gets the job done.
- Change the `CanExecute` handler to retrieve the source control's name, and then return the appropriate value.
- Remove all of the `IsEnabled` bindings from the content control.

The control names are populated at initialization, like this:

```cs
     controlsSell = new List<string>();
     controlsSell.AddRange(new string[] {
                                          "sellButton",
                                          "OptionsSellButton"
                                        });

     controlsBuy = new List<string>();
     controlsBuy.AddRange(new string[] {
                                         "buyButton",
                                         "OptionsBuyButton"
                                       });
```

The final `CanExecute` handler ended up looking like this.

```cs
  /// <summary>
  /// Determines if the command can be executed based on TicketViewModel properties.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  public void CanExecuteCustomCommand(object sender,
      CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     // NOTE: This may need more complex handling such as in ExecutedCustomCommand.
     //       Right now, it is dependent on specific control names, which is not optimal.

     // This is usually always PTTicketView, not the originating control.
     Control target = e.Source as Control;
     // This is the control that actually executes the command.
     Control orig = e.OriginalSource as Control;

     if (orig == null)
     {
        e.CanExecute = false;
     }
     else
     {
        string ctlName = orig.Name;

        if (dataContext == null)
        {
           e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        else
        {
           if (dataContext.SelectedTab != TicketViewModel.Tabs.MultiLeg)
           {
              e.CanExecute = true;
           }
           else
           {
              if (controlsBuy.Contains(ctlName))
              {
                 e.CanExecute = dataContext.IsCommandBuyEnabled;
              }
              else if (controlsSell.Contains(ctlName))
              {
                 e.CanExecute = dataContext.IsCommandSellEnabled;
              }
              else if (controlsOther.Contains(ctlName))
              {
                 e.CanExecute = dataContext.IsCommandOtherEnabled;
              }
              else if (controlsExpiries.Contains(ctlName))
              {
                 e.CanExecute = (dataContext.IsExpiriesEnabled && dataContext.IsIndicative);
              }
              else if (ctlName.Equals("DealableTypeToggle"))
              {
                 e.CanExecute = dataContext.IsRFSEnabled;
              }
              else
              {
                 e.CanExecute = true;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

With this implementation, *all* of the controls correctly change `IsEnabled` state based on the values.

Comment: Note: I've changed this implementation to use the `CommandParameter` attributes to pass in the required booleans so I can pretty much just do `e.CanExecute = e.Parameter`. We aren't using `CommandParameter` for anything else, so it's quite handy this way.